# Index out of range when using more than one sys.argv when using if statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my work so far, I keep getting this error, but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

```
all = sys.argv[1]
help = sys.argv[2]

if sys.argv[1] >=1:
    print("Test")
else:
    print 'Test'

if sys.argv[1] >=2:
    print("Test2")
else:
    print 'Test2'
```

Comment: what's the command line you're using?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the in-built module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1) to handle arguments in properly.

Answer (score 2):

By default you have only one item(with index 0) in sys.argv, and it is name of your script. To avoid IndexError try to check that arguments actually passed to your script:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    # check what sys.argv[1] is
```